# How to load multiple pictures in an Array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load multiple pictures in an Array. 
I tried it with the `Pillow` library, and I used this code:

```
image_parrot = Image.open("picturesready\\parrot\\" + photos_parrot[i]).convert("RGB")
image_numpy_parrot = numpy.append(image_numpy_parrot , numpy.asarray(image_parrot))
```

But if I use the shape method from Numpy, then its only one dimension, and I don't think I can restore them.

Did anyone know how to do this, so that I could use this array?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a 1-D array of parrot pictures where each element of the array is an N-D array of shape `(3, n_pix_wide, n_pix_high)`. To create each element, do something like:

```
#! /user/bin/env python
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('/Users/medley/Downloads/parrot.jpg', 'r').convert('RGB')
width, height = im.size

print(width, height)

rgb = np.ndarray(shape=(3, width, height))
print(rgb.shape)
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
        rgb[0, x, y] = r
        rgb[1, x, y] = g
        rgb[2, x, y] = b

print(rgb)
print(rgb.shape)
```

Then you can make that into a function and take the return value and append it to your 1-D array of pictures. Like this

```
#! /user/bin/env python
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def get_rgb_array(image_path):
    im = Image.open(image_path, 'r').convert('RGB')
    width, height = im.size
    rgb = np.ndarray(shape=(3, width, height))
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
            rgb[0, x, y] = r
            rgb[1, x, y] = g
            rgb[2, x, y] = b
    return rgb

images = ['parrot1.jpg', 'parrot2.jpg']
rgb_images = []
for path in images:
    print("Analyzing {}".format(path))
    rgb = get_rgb_array(path)
    rgb_images.append(rgb)
    _, width, height = rgb.shape
    print("{} was {} wide and {} tall".format(path, width, height))

print(rgb_images)
```

Since you didn't specify the dimensions of the numpy array that you want to produce, I simply appended each `(3, n_pix_width, n_pix_high)` array to a list called `rgb_images`